# Comparing session variables with javascript variables

Tags: javascript, c#, session

The most logical way that came to my mind was doing

```
var example2 = "Jake"
if (<%=Session["example1"]%> == example2){
   Code
}
```

However i get this error: 
The value of what is written inside that session variable is "undefined"...
so if it were a name(Bob) that's inside that session variable, it would say 
**Bob is undefined**

Anyone got a solution for me?

Comment: Please post your **rendered** HTML, verbatim, as an example.

Comment: Why would i need to post anything about html? my question didn't even concern html, @dai

Comment: And i don't understand why people downvoted my question! it's a perfectly reasonable question and i supplied all information needed!

Comment: By "rendered HTML" I mean the rendered document as sent from the server (i.e. where the `<%= %>` was replaced with the actual output) so we could see what the browser was actually receiving and running. I said HTML because the output is part of a HTML document.

Comment: @Dai, That's just  irrelevant information. I got my answer without it.

Comment: Yuval, it is not irrelevant information. We need to know exactly what the browser was parsing which caused it to give us the "undefined" runtime error. We could infer that it was missing single-quotes (for Steve Drake's answer), but what if it was numeric or JSON data?

Comment: JSON, @Dai. The document that replaced that variable's value was the login form... is that what you meant for "rendered HTML"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need ' ' around it, eg

```
var example2 = "Jake"
if ('<%=Session["example1"]%>' === example2){
   Code
}
```

Or.. " " if that's your thing :)

Also, note the === vs ==

Comment: Amazing! so simple yet i didn't know it :) You helped me plenty!!! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Just one question, why did you put '===' ?

Comment: == will type convert if needed, === wont http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-JavaScript-comparisons